# Building Sphinx Autodoc on a Google App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a Google App Engine project that I am trying to document with Sphinx. I am trying to use the [autodoc](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html) feature for many of my modules/classes/functions.

My Sphinx reST markup:

```
.. automodule:: urls
   :members: Urls
```

When I run `make html`, I get the error:

> ```sh
> WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'urls', it reported error: "No module >named appengine.api", please check your spelling and sys.path
> ```

The file `urls` imports [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/), which I believe will in turn try to import appengine.api. I don't think its possible to provide `appengine.api` to my `sys.path`. Is there some workaround?

PS. I'm not married to Sphinx. I would be open to epydoc or alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the [AppEngine SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Download_the_Google_App_Engine_SDK) and then set your PYTHONPATH before calling `make html`.

For example, I downloaded the SDK and can do this:

```
$ ls /home/jterrace/Downloads/google_appengine/google/
appengine  __init__.py  net  pyglib  storage
$ PYTHONPATH="/home/jterrace/Downloads/google_appengine/google" python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import appengine
>>> import appengine.api
>>>
```

So, you would do something like this:

```
PYTHONPATH="/home/jterrace/Downloads/google_appengine/google" make html
```